# Line color gradient pased on Z data at each point

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'll cut to the chase.
I have a series of points in (x,y) space, with a value of some measured quantity, let's call it 'z', taken at each point.

As such, I essentially have my data in 3 arrays:
xarray are the x coords of each point
yarray are the y coord of each point
zarray are the z value at each point

What I would like to do is produce a dot-to-dot line plot to each point in turn, which is very easy to do so. What I'm finding impossible is then trying to color said line using a color gradient, wherein the z value at each plotted (x,y) data point would correspond to a color on the colormap, with the shaded line segment between each point appropriately gradiated in color.

For example, let's say my Z data ranges from 10 to 0, and that I have already normalised my colormap to be from 0 to 10.

Let's also make up the following data:

```
x = [1,3,7]
y = [1,4,9]
z = [9,4,2]
```

The idea here would be that the line segment between (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) would be appropriately color gradiated between 9 and 4 on the colormap, and the line segment between (x2,y2) and (x3,y3) would be appropriately color gradiated between 4 and 2 on the colormap.

Any help would be appreciated.
Cheers

Edit: plotting library to use would ideally be matplotlib

Comment: What plotting library are you using? We need to know that to know how to help.

Comment: using matplotlib

Answer (score 0):

Matplotlib doesn't have a way to create a single line segment that is colored with a gradient. Each line in matplotlib has a single color. So if you want gradient lines, you'll have to break your line up into shorter segments and assign each sub-segment a color along the gradient. Something like this sample: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/multicolored_line.html